# Grunt task to change some information in the existing files

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, npm

I want to create some startkit for my projects, one of the task is modify some existing files with Grunt.js. As example I have file like this:

```
1. $variable-one:   one !default;
2. $variable-two:   two !default;
3. $variable-three: three !default;
```

and I want to copy part of this file into another files. 
For example, 
`line 1` in the beginning of `file1.scss`, 
`line 2` in the end of `file2.scss`, 
`line 3` in the middle of `file3.scss.` 
I find `grunt-string-replace`, but I don't shure that it can help me.